# how to programatically add access permisson like addEditors() and addViewers() in google spreadsheet through java code

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gdata-api

currently am working on google spreadsheets,i have create a login using java swing, where in the user enters the name and password.. Now based on the user i want to give VIEW and EDIT permission for specified user.. Please help me on how to implement it in google spreadsheet.. Particularly help me with addViewers(user) and addEditors(user),and step by step procedure...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the documentation on Drive API insert permissions
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

You can find the different parameters like: write, read, owner for the method permission.insert.